# Pendant Light on Track Light System

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to install a pendant light to my halo style track fixture. I purchased a pendant light from ikea and an adapter for the track light system. The name of the pendant is the nymane and I purchased a Nora lighting NT368 adapter. My question centers around the wiring of the pendant into the adapter. In the cable that attaches to the ceiling, there is only a live and neutral wire while the ground is attached to the mount. In the adapter, there is a live, neutral and ground wiring. Is there any way that I could attach the pendant without the ground and still not cause any safety issues or is it possible to just leave the wiring of the ground our altogether?[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Are you mounting the pendant light to the ceiling and powering it from the existing track?  Or mounting the pendant light to the track?

Comment: If there is no ground in the downwire then the fixture itself doesn't need a ground. What is the construction of the fixture?  Plastic?  The mounting plate that you will be discarding needs to be grounded  because it's metal.

Comment: I was going to mention what Tyson just said but I do have a few questions. First is the plate showing in the last picture part of the fixture at the end of the cord? Second is the fixture supported from the track by the cord only? Third, does this fixture have a UL or CSA stamp anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If the pendant fixture has a metal connection to that plate under normal installation, then I would recommend adding a wire somewhere inside the fixture to connect with the ground wire in the adapter.  If, however, the pendant is designed to hang purely from that 2-wire cable, then clearly the fixture doesn't need to be grounded, so just attach hot and neutral to the adapter.